# Broadcom NetLink BCM5906M driver

Tags: windows, laptop, ethernet, broadcom, drivers

I have bought a laptop  HP 6715s today, but I'm not able to find the ethernet controller driver. The drivers from Broadcom and Google are not the same version and are not compatible. Can someone tell me where can I download BCM5906M driver for Windows XP, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3356623&lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3368539&taskId=135)?